# Node.js - Firebase Functions Database onCreate not triggering

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to have my Firebase Function trigger when a child is created in the updates/GmB71KB6lXbYOfGLKNkUgIdiLb42 directory in my Realtime Database but it isn't triggering.

When I put it into a Cloud Storage trigger, it worked and my prints showed up in the log, but when I put it back into an onCreate trigger it stopped working again. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Follow-up question -- if I need to change my trigger from a Realtime Database trigger into a Cloud Storage trigger, are the first 1-2 lines (functions.database.ref(...).onCreate -> functions.storage.object().onFinalize) all I need to modify?

EDIT 2: On further investigation, I found out that if I change the trigger type to onDelete, onWrite or onUpdate, the trigger fires. When I tried to find out the type of event for onWrite by using context.eventType, it keeps coming back as undefined.

```
exports.kairosDatabaseTrigger = functions.database.ref('/updates/GmB71KB6lXbYOfGLKNkUgIdiLb42/')
.onCreate((snapshot) => {

    console.log("Starting kairos trigger")

    const content = snapshot.val;
    const photos = content.photoUrls;

    for(i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {

        const tempPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(url));
        downloadIMG(photos[i], tempPath);

        base64str = base64_encode(tempPath);
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: 'https://api.kairos.com/recognize',
            body: {
                'image': base64str,
                'gallery_name': 'gallerytest1'
            },
            headers: {
                'app_id': 'xxxxxx',
                'app_key': 'xxxxxxxxx'
            },
            json: true
        }

        request(options)
        .then(function(repos) { 
            console.log('API call succeeded');

            console.log(repos)

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // API call failed...
            console.log('API call failed');
        })

    }

});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to say exactly what you're doing that should trigger the function execution.

Comment: I'm trying to have the function trigger when I create a new child under /updates/GmB71KB6lXbYOfGLKNkUgIdiLb42/ as coded in functions.database.ref

Answer (score 1):

Just found out what was going on. I was looking for updates posted within the updates/GmB71KB6lXbYOfGLKNkUgIdiLb42 directory so I needed to specify a wildcard to capture the node itself. Instead of:

```
exports.kairosDatabaseTrigger = functions.database.ref('/updates/GmB71KB6lXbYOfGLKNkUgIdiLb42/').onCreate((snapshot) => {
```

it should be:

```
exports.kairosDatabaseTrigger = functions.database.ref('/updates/GmB71KB6lXbYOfGLKNkUgIdiLb42/{updateID}').onCreate((snapshot) => {
```